# Ionic V6 - In app Browser não abre e nem apresenta erro

Tags: angular, ionic, cordova-plugin, inappbrowser

Estou desenvolendo um APP usando Ionic V6 com Angular e Cordova, mas estou tendo um problema para utilizar o In App Browser, quando eu utilizo o app pelo computador (ionic serve) funciona normal, mas quando eu testo pelo celular (ionic cordova run android) o botão que deveria abrir a página de internet não funciona, simplesmente não acontece nenhum ação no app, nem apresenta erro no console.

Estou seguindo essa documentação: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser

Já utilizei em outros apps o In App Browser, mas com o ionic mais antigo e utilizando essa documentação: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/in-app-browser/ (que não funciona no meu app com ionic v6)

Executando o comando ionic info, tenho esses dados:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.3 (C:\Users\Gabri\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.17.0\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.1.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.2.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.2.6
   @angular/cli                  : 13.2.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 4 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.4) : 0.15.3
   native-run (update available: 1.6.0)   : 1.4.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Android\android-sdk)
   NodeJS            : v14.17.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.14.13
   OS                : Windows 10
```

No código eu uso o seguinte import:

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser/ngx';
```

O construtor:

```
constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) {}
```

E a função que abre o browser:

```
abrirProvaOuGabarito(arquivo: string) {
  this.iab.create(this.servidorCaminhoBase + arquivo, '_system');
}
```

O link gerado, seria por exemplo esse: https://plataforma.aerosafeead.com.br/Uploads/simulados/prova-1653513297.pdf

Testei também com link do google, com HTTP e HTTPS, tentei também trocando `_system` por `_blank` ou deixando sem nada, tentei também abrir a página com `window.open()` e colocando um link simples no HTML (`<a href=""></a>`), testei em dois celulares diferentes, mas o resultado é sempre o mesmo.

No meu package.json os imports são esses:

```
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^5.41.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser": "^5.43.0",
```

O InAppBrowser está nos meus providers do `app.module.ts`

E no meu config.xml adicionei apenas o `<allow-navigation href="*" />` de diferente do que vem por padrão, não sei se interfere, mas usei isso por que eu rodo videos do youtube no meu app.

Já procurei em vários lugares e nenhuma solução resolveu, não sei mais o que alterar.

---

Eu criei um novo APP para testar, um app limpo, utilizando o mesmo ambiente, e por padrão ele vem com um link na home page (blank app), após criar, executei o app com `ionic serve` e funcionou normalmente os links, mas se executar pelo celular com `ionic cordova run android`, mesmo o app estando totalmente vazio, o erro é o mesmo

Answer (score -1):

No meu codigo eu utilizo desta forma e funciona...

```
away(url: string){
    this.inApp.create(url);
}
```

Caso não funcione, estude migrar para o capacitor... não sei se tem a ver mas o cordova esta em desuso.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).